# ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord app died save no state

Tags: process, android-sdcard, kill-process, activity-manager

> > I am developing an application in which i have to download files from SD card or USB to my phone 
> >     I am using aynctask to do the same but the problem when the copying process is going on from USB drive to phone and we remove the usb device my app present activity is getting destroyed and going to previous activity
> >     When i check the logs i can see the following
> >
> > ProcessKiller: !@Process com.sec.android.quickbackup (6688) has open file /storage/UsbDriveA/Images/ØªØµÙˆÛŒØ±0004.jpg
> >     ProcessKiller: !@Sending SIGHUP to process 6688
> >     ProcessKiller: Wait for death /proc/6688
> >
> > ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{d7aacef u0 com.sec.android.quickbackup/.EasyDataTransferHome t3388}: app died, no saved state
> >
> > Please do the needful